# is mutex or event mechanism on Win32 is same as Linux mutex?

Tags: c++, linux, winapi

I am learning synchronization mechanisms on Win 32. I am trying to understand the behavior of events and mutexes. If 2 or more threads waiting for same event or mutex, only one thread will get the event or mutex, once it is available. Is my understanding correct or all the threads will become ready once the object is available?

Comment: WIN32 events and mutexes are entirely different beasts and have little in common. Further, Linux (assuming pthreads) has nothing like WIN32 events anyway. A mutex is a mutex is a mutex... they're going to behave similarly no matter what. Events are a different story.

Comment: Only one thing at the same time can have a mutex lock. But after one thread has released the mutex again, the next waiting thread will get it. In that point, it´s the same on Windows and Linux (I´m assuming you´re using a real mutex, not events)

Comment: For mutexes: Your first two sentences are correct. I do not get what 'all threads will become ready' means.  Think of a mutex as  something like a turnstile that lets only one person at a time into a room.  When that person leaves the room the turnstile then will let only one person in to the room.

Comment: mutex and the whole asynchronous thingies have become standardized in `c++11`. There shouldn't be any behavioural difference in windows vs linux.

Comment: @WorldSEnder ...other than both OS having their own platform-dependent stuff too.

Comment: Threads don't "own" events, they are used for signalling.